# Combinatorics - subset sums from a set of intergers

Tags: combinatorics

Let X be any set of 16 integers and consider all sums of exactly 6 of the numbers from X.
Prove that at least 9 of these sums diﬀer from each other by a multiple of 1000.

I'm really lost on how to attack this problem.  Since it states X can be any set, they couldn't we have the set {0..15}, and thus any 6-number sum wouldn't be a multiple of 1000?

Please help me make some sense of this question so I can work it out!

Comment: They **differ** by a multiple of $1000$.  Remember that $0$ is a multiple of $1000$.

Comment: The sums of $\{0,3\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ are both $3$ so they differ by a multiple of $1000$.  Nice problem no idea why it should be true.

Comment: Oh wow, I have no idea why I didn't see that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{16}{6}=8008$ such subsets. Put two subsets $A$ and $B$  in the same bucket if the sum of the elements of $A$ has the same remainder on division by $1000$ as the sum of the elements of $B$. There are $1000$ buckets, so one bucket has at least $9$ subsets.